# Implicit conversion to static lifetime in anyhow::Error

Tags: rust, reference

I was reading up code for `anyhow` crate in Rust. There is a [particular line](https://github.com/dtolnay/anyhow/blob/5a193636c3ebaec353bba13d62feeeb55d86f77a/src/error.rs#L76) I don't fully grasp:

```
{
 let vtable = &ErrorVTable { ... };
 construct(vtable, ...);
}

fn construct(vtable: &'static ErrorVTable, ...);
```

We seem to create an `ErrorVTable` struct, and return a reference to it which has lifetime `static. I'd expect compiler to create a struct on function stack, and return a reference to it, causing weird memory issues.

But it appears like compiler detects that this variable for all possible `E` inferred on compile time and somehow creates static variables for them? How does this actually work?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this simplified code:

```
struct Foo {
    x: i32
}

fn test(_: &'static Foo) {}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo{ x: 42 };
    test(&f);
}
```

As expected, it does not compile, with the message:

> `f` does not live long enough

However this slightly variation does compile:

```
fn main() {
    let f = &Foo{ x: 42 };
    test(f);
}
```

The difference is that in the former, the `Foo` object is local, with a local lifetime, so no `'static` reference can be built. But in the latter, the actual object is a static constant so it has static lifetime, and `f` is just a reference to it.

To help see the difference, consider this other equivalent code:

```
const F: Foo = Foo{ x: 42 };
fn main() {
    test(&F);
}
```

Or if you use an actual constant literal:

```
fn test_2(_: &'static i32) {}
fn main() {
    let i = &42;
    test_2(&i);
}
```

Naturally, this only works if all the arguments of the `Foo` construction are constant. If any value is not constant, then the compiler will silently switch to a local temporary instead of a static constant and you will lose the `'static` lifetime.

The precise rules for this *[constant promotion](https://github.com/rust-lang/const-eval/blob/master/promotion.md)*, as it is sometimes called, are a bit complicated and may be extended in newer compiler versions.